# How to change fragment instances with multiple Components?

Tags: vue.js

Here, thats my Vue file.

The `multiselect` and `classified-basic-info` component are fragment instances.

How can I change it?

```
<template> 
<div>


<div>
    <multiselect :selected.sync="selected" :options="options"></multiselect>
</div>

<div>
    <classified-basic-info :form.sync="form"></classified-basic-info>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#" @click="currentView = 'kfz'"> KFZ</a> |
    <a href="#" @click="currentView = 'kleinanzeigen'"> Kleinanzeigen</a> |
    <a href="#" @click="currentView = 'job'"> Job</a> |
    <a href="#" @click="currentView = 'immobilien'"> Immobilien</a> |

    <component :is="currentView"></component>
</div>

</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid instance fragmentation component template must have root-level container element.

Put each templates content inside root DIV element and check it. Div must be inside template, not outside like in your example:

```
<div>
  <multiselect :selected.sync="selected" :options="options"></multiselect>
</div>
```

Vue [guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance) explains this.

**Edit** Add root div to your template:

```
<template> 
    <div>
        <div>


        <div>
            <multiselect :selected.sync="selected" :options="options"></multiselect>
        </div>

        <div>
            <classified-basic-info :form.sync="form"></classified-basic-info>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="#" @click="currentView = 'kfz'"> KFZ</a> |
            <a href="#" @click="currentView = 'kleinanzeigen'"> Kleinanzeigen</a> |
            <a href="#" @click="currentView = 'job'"> Job</a> |
            <a href="#" @click="currentView = 'immobilien'"> Immobilien</a> |

            <component :is="currentView"></component>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: can you explain it to my whole template? i have wrapped all components with an div and the complete also with one div.

Comment: @WolfgangMüller If you mean that problem is not only with multiselect and classified-basic-info components, then main template must have root node too. See me update.

Comment: okay thank you. I dont know why. But with import with vue-multiselect the error was every time. Now i copied the original vue file and made a own component with it. And now it works fine.